# Seeking Canonical: Non-returning PHP Recursion

Tags: discussion, canonical, dupehammer, signpost-questions

I've scratched together a heap of open or suboptimally closed pages that are all resolved in the exact same way.

I would like to close them with a single canonical page that will best help researchers.

I don't know what criteria with which I should compare the list and single-out a top choice.

1. Can I please receive answers which nominate a best page to serve as the canonical?
2. Can you please include your reasoning (ideally in an algorithmic way) so that other curators and myself can adopt trusted techniques when collapsing loads of redundant content upon itself? (Pageviews, scores, question completeness/quality, answer quality, etc.)

If anyone finds more PHP-tagged dupes of this exact fault (which are resolved this same way), please add them as comments or edit them into my question.

To be clear, I could have stretched the topic scope of the questions to include failures to collect arrays of return data (I found several of these too), but I wanted to keep the scope VERY narrow.

| Date | Question |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | [Return Random Number but not 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1300797/2943403) |
| 2009 | [Can this recursive function go crazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1712804/2943403) |
| 2009 | [PHP function doesn't return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011778/2943403) |
| 2010 | [PHP function not returning string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108342/2943403) |
| 2010 | [Why is my recursive function not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288103/2943403) |
| 2011 | [Recursive function returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7958855/2943403) |
| 2011 | [Recursive function in PHP - how not to return false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7881637/2943403) |
| 2011 | [Recursive PHP function is not returning a result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4962789/2943403) |
| 2011 | [Recursive function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8667336/2943403) |
| 2011 | [Function not returning a result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8103310/2943403) |
| 2012 | [My recursive function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11493950/2943403) |
| 2012 | [PHP recursive function return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9380434/2943403) |
| 2012 | [Recursive function: echo works, return doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9619442/2943403) |
| 2012 | [php recursion, function doesn't return any value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13788690/2943403) |
| 2012 | [How to return true with a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9810771/2943403) |
| 2012 | [Recursive function says it's doing one thing, actually does another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10313709/2943403) |
| 2013 | [Why doesn't this PHP recursive function return the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16933503/2943403) |
| 2013 | [Php recursive function return null while variable have value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18827838/2943403) |
| 2013 | [recursion issue by calling method returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19664584/2943403) |
| 2013 | [Why doesn't this recursive PHP function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14350302/2943403) |
| 2013 | [recursive function - help returning value when calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18000410/2943403) |
| 2013 | [return an array from a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18077734/2943403) |
| 2013 | [Recursion in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17426187/2943403) |
| 2013 | [function should return array but returns NULL instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19083473/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Issue with returning value in recursive function PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27327084/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Returning a value in a recursive loop function php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25212701/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Calling recursive function from a function return only first value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21378808/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Can't figure out why this function returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21709046/2943403) |
| 2014 | [This recursive PHP function is not returning any value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27524306/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Recursive function returning null but on var dump returns a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24351498/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Recursive function return null value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21520556/2943403) |
| 2014 | [PHP Recursive function not working as expected :(](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24615249/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Recursive function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22636295/2943403) |
| 2014 | [php recursiv function "return" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22932414/2943403) |
| 2014 | [PHP Function not returning TRUE - But it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24032122/2943403) |
| 2014 | [Return a value properly from a tree with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23971275/2943403) |
| 2015 | [PHP recursive function return (true) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27817778/2943403) |
| 2015 | [How to use return inside a recursive function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624313/2943403) |
| 2015 | [PHP recursive function not returning expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32854092/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Recursive PHP function is not returning the expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33300632/2943403) (non-PHP dupe) |
| 2015 | [The 'return' keyword is not working correctly in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33374086/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Recursive function is not working in code-igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32521115/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Search through a directory in PHP, beginning at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613251/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Function is finding an entry, but not returning it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34439486/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Function with recursive call not returning the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33542475/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Recursive function never return my temp array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33771158/2943403) |
| 2015 | [PHP function returning NULL instead of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31757484/2943403) |
| 2015 | [Function returns null (returned value is not null) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33166202/2943403) |
| 2015 | [how to pass a value from a recursive function into an array in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30346049/2943403) |
| 2016 | [PHP recursive function is not working right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38087814/2943403) |
| 2016 | [Recursive function doesn't return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39328922/2943403) |
| 2016 | [Recursive function does not return array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39667394/2943403) |
| 2016 | [Funtion is not returning an array from 'else'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39736935/2943403) |
| 2016 | [PHP Recursive function not returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35736246/2943403) |
| 2016 | [Recursive function does not return any value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41244346/2943403) |
| 2016 | [PHP: Returning from a recursive array searching function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37280124/2943403) |
| 2016 | [Static variable prints the correct value but returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35587154/2943403) |
| 2016 | [RECURSIVE Function return array as NULL while var_dump before return works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37588216/2943403) |
| 2016 | [recursive function in model doesnt return anything - laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40341557/2943403) |
| 2016 | [PHP Recursion Function not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34591282/2943403) |
| 2016 | [PHP function shows result but does not return it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38859188/2943403) |
| 2016 | [php function returns null instead of string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40428865/2943403) |
| 2017 | [Laravel: recursive function not working as expected. It is returning value from wrong iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42130499/2943403) |
| 2017 | [Recursive PHP function is not returning a Boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45737883/2943403) |
| 2017 | [function not return value php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42779382/2943403) |
| 2017 | [Simple recursion returns null in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46734461/2943403) |
| 2017 | [Return in recursive function PHP laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46183814/2943403) |
| 2017 | [Recursive function return array always null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42113911/2943403) |
| 2018 | [PHP recursive function returns empty JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49736222/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Recursive function returns NULL but I can echo or var_dump()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50219602/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Return last set of array from PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51694855/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Recursive cURL function php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51741078/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Recursive function doesn't terminate on return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52668379/2943403) |
| 2018 | [PHP recursive function is not returning any value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53134288/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Recursive function including mysql does not work in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53273988/2943403) |
| 2018 | [How can I return a variable at last call of recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53686548/2943403) |
| 2018 | [PHP Recursive class returning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52050619/2943403) |
| 2018 | [PHP: counter variable in recursive function counts down before returning "1"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51479576/2943403) |
| 2018 | [php function return variable not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50560884/2943403) |
| 2018 | [function not returning array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48657365/2943403) |
| 2018 | [Function returns null if return is called within a conditional statement despite meeting the condition. Returns expected value outside of conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52771176/2943403) |
| 2019 | [How to get query result using recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56053521/2943403) |
| 2019 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/57169446/2943403 |
| 2019 | [Recursive function returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58064509/2943403) |
| 2019 | [Recursive function returns incorrect value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58092557/2943403) |
| 2019 | [Recursive PHP Star-Rating function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57254285/2943403) |
| 2019 | [Why does the method not return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58895213/2943403) |
| 2019 | [Function works inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54025743/2943403) |
| 2020 | [Function doesn't return value in recursive function php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61850703/2943403) |
| 2020 | [Recursive Function returns null value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62485867/2943403) |
| 2020 | [Recursion PHP - after one permutation why doesn't this recursive function return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63136796/2943403) |
| 2020 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/65352658/2943403 |
| 2020 | [Return statement is not working in php, although the value is present still variable on return gives null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62406985/2943403) |
| 2021 | [PHP function not returning a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66837456/2943403) |
| 2021 | [Recursive function not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67334570/2943403) |
| 2021 | [Recursive function to API returning duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70353873/2943403) |

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't one official method for picking the correct one. That said, I'd personally limit it to ones within the past five-ish years, and pick a high-scoring one, with a solid explanation. Ideally, [someone with a gold badge in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/93/php) could probobly tell which one is the best to make canonical, though. Also, IDK about the rules there, but if you find a time where [the PHP chatroom is active](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), someone there may have an opinion of the best one to make into the canonical question

Comment: Pick one with the shortest code sample in the question body.

Comment: For the record, I am a PHP gold badge holder.  I have every intention of closing every page, but this a lot of unilateral authority for one user to have.  [I'd rather seek a fair outcome in accordance with a conscientious pool of users about the best canonical.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417648/2943403)

Comment: Although I have nothing against people looking for old duplicates to clean up the site (sometimes I do that as well), finding 100 of them is a bit impractical. Usually I find just-enough such that it's very likely for an user to find the canonical linked from the first search result with almost all possible keyword combinations (although without a hammer I usually just flag/leave a comment and hope people coming across the question looks lax at the comment section, or the "linked question" pane and pick the highest scored one if there are too many existing comments)

Comment: Yes, I do find this practice of accumulating duplicates very tedious and under-appreciated.  However, my intrinsic motivation has taken over my appetite for "unicorn rewards".  I find myself hoping that more gold badgers will see the value in such overdue content curation and perform similar techniques in tag pools where they swim (and possibly elsewhere in the SE Network). It is a symptom of a systemic failure that a single, narrow topic has a hundred pages that are currently unlinked. This is not a self-solving problem. We need people to be aware, care, and take action to make things better.

Comment: Wow. Do PHP programmers know how to even use a search engine?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship no, no they do not.  Fortunately, Stack Overflow enables curatorship and empowers trusted users to mop up.

Comment: @mickmackusa Well, some must do. I looked at every question on the list, and I'm shocked: there's so many upvotes spread all over them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having reviewed all the posts (as of revision 4, "More dupes for cluster"), my inclination would be that [How to use return inside a recursive function in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624313/9473764) would be the best canonical of *them*. My reasons for this are:

- the title is relevant to the question
- the question and code are short and easy to understand;
- the answer has a reasonable explanation as well as the entire correct code
- both question and answer are upvoted and the answer is accepted

Having said that, I don't think it would be unreasonable to develop a trivial example question/answer as a community wiki (for example [using palindrome](https://3v4l.org/NlsF9#v8.1.6)) and close everything as a dupe of that.

BTW you missed one: [Why does the method not return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58895213/9473764) :)

Comment: I'd prefer to honor an existing page (given so many choices) rather than creating a new page to serve as the canonical.

Comment: Factorial probably wouldn’t be a good example: a bare expression-as-statement looks too obviously unusual to be something a naïve coder could have plausibly written. From what I can see, most examples of this pattern simply expect a bare self-call to work like tail recursion, with the innermost `return` clearing the whole recursion stack.

Comment: @user3840170 yeah, I did have that thought... it was late and it was just the first thing that came to mind. If you have a better idea please feel free to edit, otherwise I'll revisit later this morning when I get some free time

Comment: @user3840170 I've updated with a palindrome example; still reasonably simple code and perhaps an easier mistake to make?

Comment: @mickmackusa I think the issue is there are too many choices, none of which are perfect. A well-written community wiki Q&A with a simple, thoroughly explained example seems like a better idea to me.

Comment: @mickmackusa so what do you think - community wiki canonical or are you going to go with another?

Comment: I have begun closing from most recent to least recent.  I ran out of votes for today. I have decided to use the first nominated page in your answer.  I have almost closed all of 2021 through 2016.  If you'd like to continue closing, be my guest.

Comment: @mickmackusa I did the 2015s but likewise ran out of votes...

Comment: For any interested parties, ALL currently listed pages are now closed as dupe/signposts for "How to use return inside a recursive function in PHP".

Comment: @mickmackusa good job!

Answer (score 11):

PHP is hardly the only language where such problems occur.

- [Why does this recursive function return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321807/why-does-this-recursive-function-return-undefined) (JavaScript)
- [How to return a value from a recursive Python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882826/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-recursive-python-function) (Python)
- [Why does this recursive function return the wrong value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467912/why-does-this-recursive-function-return-the-wrong-value) (C++)
- [Dart: how to return value from calling a recursive function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726752/dart-how-to-return-value-from-calling-a-recursive-function) (Dart)
- [Recursive method returning undesired value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978451/recursive-method-returning-undesired-value) (C♯)
- [PL/SQL recursive function return no value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108494/pl-sql-recursive-function-return-no-value) (PL/SQL)
- [VBScript recursive function issue returning value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739788/vbscript-recursive-function-issue-returning-value) (VBScript)
- [AutoIt - Return value always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921049/autoit-return-value-always-0) (AutoIt)
- [More help needed with recursive function and returned value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109163/more-help-needed-with-recursive-function-and-returned-value) (ActionScript)
- [recursive function will not return as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837264/recursive-function-will-not-return-as-expected) (VB.NET)

Python duplicates seem particularly numerous from superficial skimming, probably because of its popularity as a teaching language, though PHP seems at least a close second.

I think this warrants a language-agnostic canonical duplicate.

Comment: I did consider this outcome (because I found some off-language dupes while Googling), I'd like to hear what other users think about this.  On one hand, it allows maximum consolidation of content.  On the other hand, having language-specific canonicals will probably help researchers relate to real examples.  Good answer.

Comment: After reading a few of these I'm leaning towards this.  Much of the problem appears to be about mentally modeling how recursion works.  [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895213/why-does-the-method-not-return-a-value#comment104055299_58895230) "I thought that he should sooner or later stumble on the first condition and just do return $value." indicates that beginners sometimes try to think of the recursion like nested if statements where returning breaks you out of the top level.

Comment: It is *very* common for beginners to think of recursion that way, because it is common for them to think of *calling a function* as if it were a "goto". This is especially evident in code where recursion is used to implement a retry for user input in a "menu" (where a `while` loop would generally be more appropriate); or where functions are used to represent "locations" in an adventure game and "exiting" a location is implemented by directly calling the function corresponding to the "destination".

Comment: Anyway, *if it means we get to clean up everything else*, I absolutely think there is room on the site for both a language-agnostic canonical, and for language-specific canonicals (mainly so that they can show language-specific syntax) that have the language-agnostic one as a "See Also".

Comment: Especially for beginner questions in common languages, I'd prefer language specific dupe targets so we don't end up just swapping "I don't understand how feature X works" problems for "I don't understand the syntax of language A".  I'm not opposed to having both language specific ones and a language agnostic one - especially if the former are created by taking the agnostic one and swapping the code to the target language, but think language specific ones are better where available.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I imagine the language-agnostic versions *not* having code in them, but simply describing how to write the code in simple (but technically precise) terms. Naturally this would only apply to questions where such an approach is feasible.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight We can have a canonical duplicate for each family of languages, or have examples for each language family in the answer(s). We don't need a "how does recursion work" for C, C++, C#, Java, Python, Swift, Javascript, PHP, etc. They all work the same, and these languages look very similar in this regard. If one fails to understand the concept because a different language of the same family was used, then one's beyond the need for help that SO can provide.