# New Collective: PHP – Scope, community, and questions

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement, php-collective

Today, the [PHP Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php) is launching on Stack Overflow.

### Why PHP?

After launching the [R Language Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language) earlier this year, we wanted to launch another collective focused on a specific language. PHP made sense given that, as with R, there is a strong sense of subcommunity around PHP and an existing community on Stack Overflow already. We’d like to involve users who are active in the PHP chat room as well as on Q&A, and determine how the current and future features of collectives can make the community and content stronger and more effective.

There are a few potential discussion topics to dive into now. Please feel free to respond to any of these prompts, or to suggest others. Discussions here could be spun off into standalone questions as needed. (Please use the tag [php-collective](/questions/tagged/php-collective) for any new questions specifically about this collective.)

### Tags and scope

The collective is currently defined by the single tag [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

**Are there other tags on Stack Overflow that are exclusively related to PHP and should be included?** Even if including them might seem redundant (since questions would likely also be tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)), it’s worth listing them and gathering the community’s thoughts together.

The focus brought by a collective brings an opportunity to assess related tags and have conversations about optimizing them.

### Content needs and community concerns

**What are potential projects that the PHP collective members might collaborate on to improve the experience for both askers and readers of PHP questions? Can any resources be improved to reduce duplicate questions and help askers avoid posting off-topic questions?**

If you’re active in the tags or in the broader PHP community on Stack Overflow, such as the PHP chat room, and have found yourself wishing for improvements in some area, post your thoughts about what the ideal scenario might be. Even if it seems unrealistic, often that can be a great starting point for ideation and meaningful change.

### Recognized Members

Recognized Member (or “RM”) is the [user role](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) specific to Collectives that has additional privileges, most notably to designate specific answers as “recommended” and to oversee the review and publication of articles. It is intended for those who would be considered subject matter experts in the collective’s topic, or perhaps in some specific portion of the topic. While we generally see the RM group as the community leaders within each of these collectives, it’s up to the community to decide how the role operates in that regard.

The Recognized Member role in the PHP Collective will be open to any user with a gold or silver badge in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag, and who has not been suspended in the past 12 months. Anyone who qualifies can express their interest in a comment or answer on this post. Those interested are also welcome to inquire about the RM role via the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?topic=15) if they feel more comfortable that way.

However, the Recognized Member role is not required to be part of helping define how the collective operates. The first step in being involved is participating in the discussion on this post!

### General questions

The PHP Collective is intended as a space for a subcommunity to grow and thrive in ways that make sense for this area of practice. Community members well-versed in all things PHP are best suited to determine how to leverage the current features of the collective and to identify the areas that could most benefit from further development.

**What questions do you have about the PHP Collective? What opportunities or challenges do you see ahead?**

Please note: the answers and discussion here are intended to be specific to the PHP Collective. If you have thoughts or feedback about collectives in general, please share those on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425532/launching-2-new-collectives-php-and-nlp).

Comment: I'm not interested in collectives or what, but because I watch this tag, a SHOWY rectangle appeared on the right sidebar today and told me about this event. I just want to know if this rectangle will always be there? Are there any settings that can remove it?

Comment: @shingo only adblock/userscripts

Comment: "*What are potential projects [...] to improve the experience for both askers and readers of PHP questions?*" => Why not include Answerers as well...?

Comment: @chivracq projects could include things tag cleanup (finding questions that are mistagged and fixing them), updating tag wikis (I think the [tag:php] one is pretty robust but there may be related ones that need work), and coming up with strategies to keep the content healthy (such as introducing a tag warning for a commonly misused tag, etc).

Comment: @chivracq we hope the collective can improve the experience for everyone who works with PHP on SO, but we specifically mentioned askers and readers because as people searching for information to solve their problems they may need more support than those providing information. That said, if you have ideas on how to improve things for question answerers we would love to hear them!

Answer (score 17):

> The collective is currently defined by the single tag php.
>
> Are there other tags on Stack Overflow that are exclusively related to PHP and should be included?

Statements and questions like these signal to me that you have no idea why the community needs a collective for PHP. Why would you create a collective before you even know the extent of it? I see no reason given other than «we have PHP in our community». What’s the reason just having tags for the topic isn’t enough?

Seeking feedback? Great! But why not delay the creation of the collective until after you actually know more about it? I’m left wondering: what drives this need for a PHP collective? Is it for marketing purposes? I don’t know, and it doesn’t seem like you do either. I’m curious as to what specifically led you to believe that there needs to be a collective for PHP, other than «sense of subcommunity». What specifically will the existence of such a collective make to PHP related subjects on Stack Overflow, and how will this impact the rest of the network?

Answer (score 14):

I potentially see two tags:

1. [phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpunit) - This is a PHP library (OOP) and a utility to run tests against PHP code. It is maintained and developed aligned with PHP core development and implements the phpt protocol which is also used for PHP core (albeit IIRC not from phpunit, just noting).
2. [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php) - Composer is a PHP dependency manager (user-land) now  for many years. Albeit it does not cover the whole ecosystem any longer, it has created a new one and IMHO it has done this quite well. And even while using it introduces many risks, many PHP projects rely on it nowadays for their dependencies, including during development (or, *shrug*, production). (most PHP projects today are Composer projects and for me as a PHP developer it is a mystery why that tag is not just [composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer), but I've never looked)

In general the tags in the PHP Q&A have the problem that users are tagging for example Laravel or WordPress questions with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php), albeit those are technically unrelated to the question. But that is a different problem with how Stack Overflow organizes the data (begging for contributions, and there you have them).

This last remark is only a comment. The future has to tell whether or not siloing within a collective adds to the burden or is of help. I'm ok with the experiment.

Comment: *"[...] have the problem that users are tagging for example Laravel [...]"* - If a question tagged `laravel` has PHP code in it (which, being a PHP framework, 95% of them do), I generally edit it to include a the `php` tag for a couple reasons. 1) Visibility. Many people who know PHP can answer Laravel questions; a lot of them are basic syntax issues or logical approach questions. If a user doesn't know Laravel, they can ignore that tag. 2) Syntax Highlighting. Yes, this can be done via edits to include `lang-php`, or `php` next to code blocks, but the `php` tag does this automatically.

Comment: I'd add a link for tags you are suggesting showing questions tagged with them but not PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpunit+-php

Comment: @TimLewis: Thanks for the feedback, and yes, for the code-blocks I've completely forgotten, only had visibility in mind as the reason why people are adding it. So thanks for the reminder, its easy to not see the wider picture as so often.

Comment: No problem! I've seen a couple Laravel posts where the `php` tag was edited out, even though there is still PHP code in it, but the question is more about other things, like `.htaccess`, `nginx/apache` stuff, etc. There's definitely some validity for those removals, and ultimately there's always going to be a bit of a grey area with this, but just wanted to include my reasoning as someone who contributes to that "problem" (and the misuse of tags can be a problem, so I don't disagree completely with your original statement ). Cheers!

Comment: This is a very interesting conversation. I wonder if coming up with some sort of guidance or best practices around how to use [tag:php] and related tags in these kinds of "grey area" questions could be a worthwhile project for the collective to take on?

Comment: @Sasha Sorry, missed this. It is an interesting topic, especially seeing some of the edits to questions recently (by hakre and others) adding or removing the `php` tag. My 2¢ is that it ultimately is a case-by-case situation; many `laravel`-tagged questions don't need the `php` tag, as they end up as SQL, JS or configuration (`.htaccess`, `nginx`, `apache`, etc.) questions. I don't think I've ever **removed** `php` from `laravel` questions, since it is a PHP framework, but I can understand the reasoning why it would be in some cases. As long as we don't get in tag wars, it's a minor thing. 

Answer (score 8):

Here is a SEDE query giving the list of co-occurring tags with php along with some stats: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1717890/total-count-of-co-occuring-tags-with-a-target-tag?TargetTag=php

You would add [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli) or [pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) to the collective, but obviously not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

[image]

p.s. Thank you, flower!

Answer (score 6):

Here are some categories of tags that are always PHP related:

- Software that is exclusively PHP, such as `laravel`, `codeigniter`
- Related *sub-tags* such as `laravel-5`, `codeigniter-helpers`
- PHP tools such as `phpcodesniffer`, `phpstorm`
- Community and standards related tags such as `php-fig`, `psr-1`

Comment: Laravel, CodeIgniter, Zend, Symfony, CakePHP,  Fat-Free, and those are just frameworks. Thé list will be massive.

Comment: @miken32 have you noticed when people ask questions related to these frameworks, do they also tend to tag PHP? We want to avoid accidentally excluding relevant questions from the collective, but we could potentially take on a tag cleanup project to address this.

Comment: @Sasha for Laravel, which I primarily deal with, most of the questions are tagged with PHP. Sometimes [tag:php] isn't relevant to the question, but those cases are definitely a small minority.

Comment: @Sasha They probably add that tag because the question contains PHP code and not, for example, JavaScript code. It happens with Drupal questions too. Even if the question shows PHP code, I am not sure somebody who just knows PHP is able to answer to Drupal questions, though, when the question is really a question about code to use with Drupal.

Comment: As counter example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722601/livewire-validation-with-custom-rule-doesnt-show-error is tagged [tag:php] and [tag:lavarel], but the question is not about PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Tags like `php-8` `php-8.2` `php-7` ... are not all co-tagged with `php` which is ... for a reason? Anyway, I thought I'd mention the obvious.

TLDR:

I feel this collective would better serve the PHP language and its core extensions without branching to include frameworks and related tags. If a tag is big enough then it should have its own collective.

There's a lot to cover just under the `php` tag alone.

You know, for me, to find a question about PHP I need to scroll through `doctrine-orm` `zend-framework2` `laravel-cashier` `amazon-web-services` `facebook-php-sdk`, none of which I am interested in or have any knowledge at all of. Is it just me?

I can feel the [systemantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemantics) brewing.

Comment: Interesting point. I feel that often an asker will add a framework tag for context, and it is the answerers who understand what the best tags would have been. So a question about a framework is often answered with "You should use this language feature / core function". Therefore I think that trying to focus the collective on the language itself based on tags would exclude posts like that.

Comment: Do you think it would make sense for the collective to take on a project of systematically retagging questions that are missing the PHP tag? We would have to agree on where it does and doesn't belong of course, but that could help to avoid excluding content that really should be included.

Comment: I think retagging question that include PHP is useful somewhat? I don't know how search engine will react to it, but mostly It's useful in someway. If there are experience for contribution point, it seems tangible tho?

Comment: curious, I tried to search for [php] and couldn't find any of the version tags. so i tried just `php` and the search automatically makes it a tag search (ie changes the search to `[php]`). but on the collective side of things, i don't think the collective should be "defined" by framework tabs. any answer that includes a PHP language feature would then link to PHP and the collective.if that makes sense, or is gramatically correct, i don't like to include the overhead of a spell-checker or grammar thingy

Comment: Oh I misunderstood one aspect of collectives and that is the trusted answers. If an answer to a php framework question is by a representative of the collective then I think we should mark it as a trusted answer by the collective. I'm not sure how that ties into the whole tag thing though

Comment: You can still filter questions by tags. I find the suggestion of creating collectives for every "big" tag a bit shortsighted.

Comment: @Sasha Can a tag belong to more than one collective, or can it be a member of at most a single collective?

Comment: @chivracq (Curious that you should mention that, seeing as your own comments have so much annoying non-standard formatting and abbreviations.)

Comment: @tripleee Yeah well..., thanks for the Ping anyway... I've retracted my DV, thanks to Peter's Edit. // Interesting last sentence btw, about "[Systemantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemantics)", I didn't know the term, I only understood its meaning after reading the Article on 'Wikipedia'. (Sbd might want to add the Link to the Answer...)

Comment: @AndreasdetestsAIhype at this time we don't have any tags that are in multiple collectives, and I think that is something we would generally want to avoid. That said a question can be in multiple collectives if it has a tag from each.

Comment: @Sasha So what do you do once a language specific framework tag (that’s part of a language-specific collective), suddenly becomes relevant at great scale outside the scope of the collective it belongs to? For instance, if you had an Objective-C collective in 2014.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact I'm not sure what you mean. How would Objective-C become a tag that is relevant at great scale out side of the scope of its collective?

Comment: I understand now, because swift shares frameworks with objc? I like the idea sasha had in another comment to include a prefix like `php-extension-*` so for your example there would be `objc-extension-*` and `swift-extension-*` which will reference the 'same' extension but in their language specific context.

Comment: @yarns Yes, Apple frameworks available in both languages is something I had in mind when mentioning Objective-C. The suggested solution, by using tags including both the framework, and the language, is a bad solution. We already have separate tags, so you'd already tag the questions by using the separate ones. That said, the solutions in both languages, are nearly identical. There is no reason to have different questions for them. Same thing with GLFW or SDL, for instance. I don't care if the solution I get, is in C, C++ or Java. It's the same anyway.

Comment: @yarns Unless, of course, that the solution uses some specific constructs only available in a single language. In that case, tag accordingly.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact Yes I agree. I need to find out more on collectives and tags, I'm not sure how the tags actually relate to the collective. Will they just be linked or what purpose does it serve? Does a question with a PHP tag act differently in any way than if it wasn't linked to the collective?

Comment: @yarns I think the only difference is that if it’s tagged as belonging to a specific collective, you get a bunch of really annoying, flashy, disturbing elements on the page.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact I think this relates to your posted question [Collectives Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-tags), in particular the last statement.

Answer (score 5):

I can't imagine a better suited group of users to combat the disgusting amount of content redundancy on Stack Overflow.

[Cooperative, democratic, topic-scoped curation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417648/2943403)

We can all agree that we don't *actually* need [95 sign posts for a narrow problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418239/2943403), right?

Answer (score 2):

What is the point of adding a "recommended" label on the only visible answer (with a >100 score, mind you) on the page???

[What to do with mysqli problems? Errors like mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 must be of type mysqli_result and such](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488/2943403)

Are we just adding noise with recommendations?  Are recommendations arbitrarily sprinkled around as a non-bounty super-thanks from badgers?  What is the criteria? What is the letter of the law and what is the spirit of the law?

More generally, is it not obvious that the authors of non-recommended answers will feel put down that an SME has not deemed their answer worthy? Where is the value? We already have votes and green ticks.

Comment: This potentially should be its own meta post. Honestly, I still have a hard time decide what needs to be recommended, what should not be, and what can but does not need to be recommended. Although it will be different for each collective, a general discussion around this subject would be beneficial. Where's the value? e.g., older posts where the most upvoted or accepted answers are outdated. Keep in mind that usually the first recoms are experimental.

Comment: And honestly, if you feel bad about for "authors of non-recommended answers", what do you think about adding a flair on each and every answer by RMs? I detest that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424338/remove-recognized-by-xyz-collective-text-from-the-recognized-member-rms-fla/424434#424434

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ I have read your post (prior to writing my answer) and fully agree.  About my answer here, I thought the reason for adding the trending sort option was to combat the time-weighted dominance of older posts over newer posts. If there is no clear rule on in/appropriate recommendations, then it too easily allows SMEs to enforce their lone opinion on the perceived correctness/legitimacy of specific answers. Shouldn't such a feature lean toward democratic tooling (if it is needed at all)?

Comment: We brought that up early on, but the discussion died out really quick (see the beginning of this chatroom, only needs a couple of scrolls: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252171/r-language-collective). I didn't post on MSO because I knew I'd get answers mostly focused on why we need this in the first place (which I agree to some extent, but as I said, outdated answers are a great use-case for this feature). Now that we have it, a discussion focused on how to use it in a "safe and efficient" manner seems warranted (of course there will be differences among collectives).

Comment: Recognized Members use their judgement to determine if an answer should be recommended, there is no set rule about it. However, its possible to develop guidelines about when answers should be recommended in a particular collective, if that is preferred by the community. If you have ideas about what would make sense for PHP feel free to add them here.

Answer (score 1):

Other tags to include:

1. [pecl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pecl) - *"PECL is a repository for PHP Extensions, providing a directory of all known extensions and hosting facilities for downloading and development of PHP extensions."* https://pecl.php.net/
2. [pear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pear) - *"PEAR is a repository of PHP software code, designed to offer some functionality not built into PHP core."* https://pear.php.net/

While neither are part of the [PHP.net engine source](https://github.com/php/php-src), they both are exclusively tied to the PHP project itself.

Along these same lines:

- [xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xdebug) - *"Xdebug is a PHP extension with developing aids, a profiler, an interactive debugging, and a code coverage information gatherer."*
- [intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intl) - *"Intl is a PHP extension which give ability to use Unicode, software internationalization (I18N) and globalization (G11N) from the ICU library."*

As a side note, [intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intl) is misapplied to questions covering the `Intl` class in Dart and Javascript. It may need to be clarified.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions! When you say the intl tag needs to be clarified, what are you thinking? Should there be separate tags for the PHP context versus the Dart and Javascript context? Or perhaps a tag warning that explains when to use it and when not?

Comment: @Sasha Separate tags. I'd label all of those tags as `php-extension-*` or `*-php-extension` to be clear what they are. E.g., `php-extension-intl` or `xdebug-extension-intl`.