# Stop closing duplicate pages; instead withhold rep on signposts

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, signpost-questions

### The Pain Points:

1. For askers who treat SO as a help desk, a dupe closure is a point of frustration because they want to receive answers specifically tailored to their question.
2. For answerers who treat SO as a help desk (and *say* that they aren't here for the rep gains [...pfft]), a dupe closure is a point of frustration because tailored answers cannot be posted while the page is closed.
3. For duplicate close voters who strive to prevent the accumulation of redundant content and rep farming, FGITW help-deskers and non-curators create frustration.
4. For duplicate close voters who want to give tailored advice about how to implement the dupe target's advice, they can only shoehorn poorly-formatted text into comments under the question.
5. For careful/discerning answerers who are wary of answering a question which has a high probability of being a duplicate, they must burn minutes hunting for duplicates (while other users post carefree answers) despite being knowledgeable enough to answer immediately.
6. Answerers are not meant to also vote to close duplicates because it can be seen as a technique to block competing answers from being posted.
7. Despite SO's documented goal of getting answers on a specific topic in one place, duplicate close voting does not signal answerers to transfer their unique insights to the dupe target(s).
8. <s>Despite SO's documented appreciation for *some* duplicated content, duplicate closed questions count toward a question ban.</s> False asssertion.
9. While some questions can be legitimately closed as a duplicate AND have some other aspect that makes the page unsuitable as a signpost, the system does not permit that dual distinction.
10. Eliminating the reputation benefit of asking and answering duplicate questions can only be combatted by downvoting content (which might not be merited based on question quality) and/or by deleting the closed page. For content curators, these actions are tedious, significantly draining of time, and can lead to revenge voting and/or re-open/close/undelete/delete wars.

### The Solution:

1. Instead of changing the terminology from "**Duplicate**" to "**Resolved Elsewhere**" (which I have previously suggested), the new page status should be called something positive/optimistic: "**Potential Signpost**".  The subtext for the page status can be like: "**Significantly unique questions which have been resolved elsewhere may be retained to help direct readers to recommended advice.**"
2. All upvotes and downvotes on the page will be tracked/presented normally, however, **all reputation changes** (including rep cost for downvoting) **will be held in escrow** (potentially indefinitely) while the page is marked as a "potential signpost". Yes, this is retrospective -- all rep changes will be reverted upon the page becoming a signpost.
3. Contrary to all other close vote options, which indicate that the question is unfit for the site, **there will be no answer-block implemented**. This means that after a question has been labelled as a potential signpost, answers can continue to be posted -- even by the user who voted the page as a potential signpost, if they so wish.
4. This feature will be **deliberately unattractive for rep-motivated contributors to bother posting an answer on potential signposts**. Adding unique insights to the open target page(s), will be the simplest way to gain rep. As a secondary benefit, if a user who answered feels that the question and its resolving insights are sufficiently distinct from all other pages on SO, then they can vote to remove the potential signpost label.  If successful, the rep points will no longer be in escrow.
5. To prevent unilateral selfishness in removing potential signpost status to gain rep, **there should be no "un-hammer" privilege** (except for moderators) for the potential signpost label.  Honestly, there would no longer be a reason to rush the decision because answers can already be freely posted.

### Wins:

1. Askers who ask good, clear questions will be allowed to receive answers even if they ask a question that has been asked/resolved elsewhere.
2. Answerers don't have to wait to post an answer after searching; they can rush an answer, then go hunting for a page which covers the same narrow topic.
3. Close voters don't need to rush to close for the sake of rep farming prevention. When the page is eventually closed, all temporarily earned rep will be withdrawn and held in escrow.
4. Those who would have ordinarily voted to reopen a borderline question just so they could answer will no longer need to vote to reopen and wait to answer; they can answer and express their argument for uniqueness in their answer.
5. Users who too zealously delete questions to prevent other users from earning rep from answering duplicates will no longer need to bother voting to delete -- while a potential signpost, no rep benefits will occur.
6. This new scheme will motivate users to seek earlier posted questions and post answers there for a real chance to earn rep -- this will breathe new life into pages that have been collecting dust.
7. SO and 3rd party search engines will have MORE total content on a potential signpost because answers were not blocked -- this will increase the ability to find vital keywords/phrases.
8. Ultimately, this gives users more freedom to share insights while reducing the grumpiness that many users encounter in the Q&A.
9. At a later stage, when signposts are accumulated, it may be appropriate to merge, reverse signpost directions, or delete pages based on their content quality.

### Some Additional points:

1. Answers, while specifically resolving the asked question, may include compelling points regarding why the question is different/nuanced versus the page(s) to which the signpost points.  This should not only help curators to resolve disputes, but also inform the asker and future readers about nuances.
2. Since this "experiment" may or may not be successful in creating a positive net impact, this feature should only be in effect for newly asked questions from the datetime when this feature is officially deployed.
3. In terms of question bans, it should neither be a good nor a bad thing that a user asks a duplicate question.  If they ask a good, clear, on-topic question which happens to become a good signpost, then they are not doing any harm. If a user is posting low-value, unclear, off-topic questions, then this is obviously not desirable regardless of if the question has been asked or resolved elsewhere.  Potential signpost status should not count toward a question ban.
4. Voters will need a UX separation for voting a question as a potential signpost versus an off-topic/unfit question.  Ideally, volunteers should be able to signal both when appropriate -- that a question is, for example, resolved elsewhere AND unfit for the site under the other criteria.
5. Some thought should be given to the how Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badge calculations should work in the event that large sums of rep are released from escrow.
6. If this feature proves to be beneficial, then it can be incrementally applied to earlier years of content.  If this feature proves to be harmful, it will be very easy to revert the applied changes -- all rep is taken out of escrow, question bans can be recalculated, and signpost pages will be closed as duplicates.

Comment: [*Closing is a fairly weak signal when it comes to q-banning; voting is king*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259927)

Comment: *"For askers who treat SO as a help desk, a dupe closure is a point of frustration because they want to receive answers specifically tailored to their question."* I must admit, and this might seem a little "harsh", but *good*. [so] ***isn't*** a helpdesk, so users *shouldn't* be treating it like one. It's not a surprise that they have a poor experience as they aren't using it as it's intended. Just like when you use a hammer to put a screw in a wall.

Comment: I'm missing the angle that some\* people only ask to get answers, and some\* only answer to solve questions - both regardless of rep. The proposed changes would do nothing to limit this, and in fact would likely promote this. This has a potential to significantly *increase* such Q&A and thus curation effort; compare to how "answering in comments" is often discouraged for precisely the same issue. (\*"some" people are likely "many" people, but I could not motivate myself to drudge through the SO main feed lately.)

Comment: Would the reputation effects be retroactive (already gained rep before someone votes to close as signpost is removed) or reactive (only up/downvotes _after_ closing are not counted)? If it is the first then it is open to revenge closing (as was the criticism to earlier 'let's remove rep from duplicates' proposals), if it's the second then it does not stop FGITW/rep farming.

Comment: What I'm also missing is the interaction with actual, current signpost functionality. Unanswered duplicates are an instant redirection to the dupe target for many users at the moment. Allowing superfluous answers ("tailored advice about how to implement the dupe target's advice") would make this simple rule inapplicable.

Comment: *"Askers who ask good, clear questions will be allowed to receive answers even if they ask a question that has been asked/resolved elsewhere."* Can you elaborate on why closing as a duplicate *doesn't* give the user an answer? If the answer to their question exists somewhere else (on the site), but instead of for the *n*th day of the week and the variable is called `MyDate`, it's for the *x*th day with a variable called `Foo`, why do we need a 2nd near identical question?

Comment: @ThomA the near identical question can still be deleted by delete voters is insufficiently unique to the community.  This feature just allows a less cutthroat, yet less incentivized environment regarding dupe questions.

Comment: How does the holding rep in escrow work? Who will decide if the label is lifted / applied and rep changes applied/escrowed?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because the linked and related lists on the right side of the page are so poorly populated for the tags that I monitor, I don't need the auto-redirect as much as I need better suggestion lists.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the reopening would work the same as closing does now -- three reopen votes will do.  Then all rep in escrow would be released.  If the page is later deemed to be a potential signpost, all rep changes are put back in escrow.

Comment: @Marijn well if there are revenge closings, that will be identifiable because closing is not an anonymous activity. And yes, all rep earned before or after the page became a signpost will be moved to escrow.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, I'm not sure what "the linked and related lists on the right side of the page" or whatever "suggestion lists" you refer to has to do with auto-redirect to duplicate targets. At most those seem to be the opposite direction (going from target to duplicate) of redirection.

Comment: I'm saying that I personally hold no value in the auto-redirect feature.  Manual redirect is fine with me.  The system should let me decide where I navigate to.

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay, so does the proposal here directly-or-indirectly follow that specific personal preference of yours or not?

Comment: If the duplicate target is upvoted, then the community **cannot** delete that qusetion, @mickmackusa, so that scenario is unlike to occur, I, for example, cannot vote to delete [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group), which I *frequently* end up closing qusetions as duplicates of.

Comment: Your comment also, however, doesn't answer the question I asked: Why does closing a question as a duplicate *not* provide the asker with answers?

Comment: "Contrary to all other close vote options, which indicate that the question is unfit for the site, there will be no answer-block implemented." - One of the **main purpose** of the current duplicate closure is **preventing answers**. A dup-hammer makes the duplicate closure faster exactly for preventing new answers for a duplicate question as soon as possible. I agree that *sometimes* a tailored answer looks suitable. But for every such good answer there will be 100 answers which are plain copy of existing ones, and thus useless and even harmful for the site.

Comment: @Mister this feature doesn't mention or care at all about redirecting users directly to other pages.  If the best search result SEO-wise is a signpost, you arrive at the signpost and just like how duplicate closures look now, the page tells you that there is another page containing resolving advice.  If you NEED auto-redirecting, then post an answer on my question that describes the parts of the feature that you would change in order to support it.

Comment: @ThomA this feature requires the breakage of that old/current thinking. You no longer NEED to delete redundant pages -- they become the neutered slaves to their resolving target page.  If the signpost is off-topic or low-quality, downvote it.  If it is negatively scored it can be deleted it because it is unfit content.  The more signosts SO has on a topic, the easier it will be for researchers to find what they need. Because there is no rep gain in answering signposts, there won't be a rush to waste time answering questions which were resolved elsewhere, nor a rush to delete.

Comment: @ThomA the signpost IS expected to be resolved by the target page.  However there are fringe cases where the new asker is struggling to implement the advice with their code or if a contributor simply wants to spell out the advice explicitly.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, currently closing dupes does prevent answers, but not retrospectively -- so FGITW users know that if they rush an answer, they can beat the curators. As a curator/closer, I hate this "game". I want to disincentive the speed answering. I want people to mark new duplicates and post unique insights on earlier questions because...

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.) The fact the signpost has answers is secondary to the fact that the target is the true magnet -- that is the place where answerers actually earn rep.  The motivation is simple.

Comment: Those with dupe hammers can still hammer signposts -- it is the same skill and the same action. The difference is that the new hammering destroys rep changes, instead of limiting answers.

Comment: *" However there are fringe cases where the new asker is struggling to implement the advice"* and there's a feature for that, the [edit] feature. Their can demonstrate their attempt(s) to implement the solution(s) and show why it isn't working.

Comment: Limiting (stopping) answers is the goal though; @mickmackusa . Removing that makes the point of duplicates pointless, both literally and figuratively.

Comment: @ThomA of course that true. I personally don't expect myself to mark signposts AND post an answer very often.  It is a luxury choice, if I feel like it.  The power in this feature is that answering signposts has NO rep benefits and therefore motivates contributors to post their answers elsewhere.

Comment: So you want to have to now read 10's of questions for multiple different solutions for the same question, rather than 1? I, personally, would find that UX awful, and I'm sure many others would too. Fortunately, the duplicate feature at the moment stops that.

Comment: @ThomA limiting answers doesn't NEED to be the goal.  We use that unrewarded content to improve the search engine performance of the signpost.  If researchers want to see where the best answers are pooled, they follow the signposts to where content has been consolidated and rewarded

Comment: @ThomA that problem is ALREADY here.  That horse has bolted. Stack Overflow is a toilet of redundancy. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418239/2943403  There has been nothing done to adjust user behavior.  Helpdeskers spray answers all day long and do not care about curation because they are getting rewarded.  This feature endeavors to educate users that if they want to be rewarded, they need to post their insights on the most appropriate page.

Comment: Nothing can be done to change the user behaviour short of exterminating a swath of human kind that even Thanos would deem excessive.

Comment: I fully believe that if I want to have any chance having a proposal taken seriously, I'll need to get Shog to post it for me.  The outcome would be totally different.  I am so tired of being the lead hammerer in the tags that I monitor. It is no fun and seemingly pointless because I can't outrace the helpdeskers and I can't delete everything.  It just grinds me down.

Comment: So you're using behaviour of others doing what doesn't align with the goals of the site as a reason to make those things allowable..? Nope, that just cements my opinion of this being a terrible idea.

Comment: withholding rep when a post is ~~~closed as a duplicate~~~ marked as a signpost puts even more weight behind closing as a duplicate. It means suddenly this action of pointing users to the best answer now influences the reputation people earn from their contributions. That seems like it'd be even more problematic than the current system.

Comment: @mickmackusa "you arrive at the signpost and just like how duplicate closures look now, the page tells you that there is another page containing resolving advice" That is not how dupes work for many people and I am trying to find out whether the proposal intentionally ignores the consequences of this, or whether you are just not aware. Whether changing that would go counter to the spirit of this suggestion or would just flesh it out is important and I cannot propose changes without knowing that.

Comment: @ThomA clearly this feature disincentivizes posting answers on dupes.  You understand that, right?  Answerers can ONLY earn rep when they answer a non-signpost.  I am not sure how there could be a misunderstanding.

Comment: @KevinB correct.  I am banking on the fact that most people are rep motivated.  Making a question a signpost will indicate that they have not posted an answer on the ideal page. They are not punished for answering a signpost, but they aren't rewarded either.

Comment: I understand that you want answers to the same question all over the place, @mickmackusa , and I strongly disagree with that. I understand you want to service users that treat the site as a helpdesk, and I strongly disagree with that.

Comment: @Mister if you need auto redirecting even if the signpost has answers, I could agree to that.  I guess I just don't  personally care about that nuance.

Comment: @ThomA Questions and answers are ALREADY all over the place.  I know this because I spend a ridiculous amount of my time herding these cats and voting delete them.  But I cannot contend with the flood.  We need another way. I do not personally desire a helpdesk, but I acknowledge that there are people on this site who do.  My feature was a compromise to get progress.

Comment: "The difference is that the new hammering destroys rep changes, instead of limiting answers." - so basically, you expect that people will move their answers to get rep, and also stop voluntarily answering because they won't get rep - and that this is better than simply preventing them from answering in place... somehow? Perhaps you might consider that people who write *good* content are often much more intrinsically motivated, and already recognize very well that the reputation system [is horribly broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/).

Comment: @Karl the system does a very poor job of indicating to new/unaware contributors that they should close duplicates and then post any unique insights on the dupe target.  I believe this feature will very naturally coerce contributors to contribute better.  Because rushed answers "beat" the page closure AND earn rep points from "upvote pixies", there is no learning curve -- these rushing answerers never learn to vote to close or post on older pages. I am less concerned with addressing "good contributors", it is the ignorant contributors that I feel need educating.

Comment: Strongly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230507/duplicates-mark-ii-canonicals-more-aggressive-duplicate-prevention

Comment: I don't want to dupe-hammer this quite yet, but I'm seeing a __lot__ of overlap with [your earlier suggestion about duplicate closures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407353/lets-make-it-okay-to-answer-then-mark-a-question-as-a-duplicate-without-closing)...

Comment: Well, I am continuing to adjust my plea for change in the hope of finding the goldilocks zone of compromise to satisfy the gatekeepers and the helpdeskers.  Stack Overflow is not grooming new users to curate.  There are too few users doing the heavy lifting.  We need something to turn the tide.  Burnout is real.  Ultimately, you only have entropy when we run out of curators.

Comment: For the record, @ThomA once said: ["_Sometimes an answer on a duplicate can be more useful than the dupe target because it uses a method not on the dupe. moving the answer to the other question is likely wrong, as it wouldn't make sense on the other question. I do, however, strongly agree that disincentivising answering duplicate questions is something i would like to see; I get fed up of the amount of times certain questions get the same answer._"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417601/change-the-stigma-regarding-signposts#comment905949_417601) and 15 others Liked it.

Comment: For the record, that doesn't invalidate any of my comments here.

Comment: Well... I commend your energy and time investment. But the way things are done now is established lore, you're appealing to an immovable object. The only successful change is a small move. A very, very small move. Certainly not a whopper like this one. So ultimately, this is only worth the fiery discussion and tug 'o war that it'll invoke. I hope you realize that and don't come out of this disheartened.

Comment: We definitely don't want gatekeepers because the next thing behind it is Gozer.

Comment: Many of the downvoters of this question are "gatekeepers" that want to make contributing to Stack Overflow "difficult". I believe my daily curation routine also makes me a "gatekeeper". I close a lot of dupes and vote to delete redundant content often.

Comment: _"Blah blah people that disagree with me are being malicious"_ Well there goes your credibility. No, Mick. Your suggestion here just isn't good.

Comment: I never called anyone malicious.  I aligned my routine behaviour with other people who close and delete content.  I wonder if people who read this page perceive me as someone who panders to the helpdesk camp.  I do not want Stack Overflow to be helpdesk, but I understand that Stack Overflow's success model partly leverages the fact that people can ask for support very easily.

Comment: _"Many of the downvoters of this question are "gatekeepers" that want to make contributing to Stack Overflow "difficult""_ You're claiming that people are being malicious, here. Contributing being "difficult" is ___never___ the intended goal/purpose of any Meta regular here. The purpose of all of that feedback is that contributions are of ___high quality___.

Comment: And yet, Stack Overflow has a persistent quality problem.  Obviously something needs to change user behavior.  Keeping things the same doesn't appear to be working.  Curators are struggling to keep up with the flood of redundant/bad content.  There are too few with the will and ability to improve content.

Comment: @Shog9 I wonder if you specifically find any points in my question to be valuable/salvageable.  Might you express which points you could support and which points you'll never support and why?  This question was meant to be a compromise between how I think Stack Overflow should be while not alienating/offending people who don't use the site as I believe they should.  I guess I'm trying to figure out just how far away my feature is from palatable and why.

Comment: @mickmackusa and that's not a problem with the curators. The problem is in lacking tooling. The problem is in lacking effort from SE's side with their quantity over quality changes over the last few years. That you even suggest that the _curators_ are the problem is absurd.

Comment: No the problem is "Stack Overflow". It was designed for a different mentality than what is common now. I would actually argue it doesn't have enough gatekeeping at this point, it lets too many people in that are in blissful ignorance thinking that this site is going to do their homework for them. If this site wants to exist as it is in the world today, it needs to really change its lingo while inviting people in.

Comment: Your solution mirrors others that have been suggested before, with some suggestions going back over a decade. It is, on the whole, quite reasonable. I suspect you're struggling because you've sorta jumped the gun in generalizing a lot of the behaviors / motives you seek to address: they're all recognizable, but without specific examples tied together with an overarching narrative... Well, they remind me of the sort of troll who loudly declares, "America is a nation of hypocrites and scofflaws!" - without putting in the effort to cite the various laws that are routinely and blithely violated.

Comment: Right.  I did assume that people who have been volunteering for years would just accept my observations as truths.

Comment: Your observations are coloured by your own bias and opinion. Your interpretation of these observations seems very subjective... So no, they're not simply "accepted as truths".

Comment: @Cerbrus which of my observations do you find flawed?

Comment: Well, point 1 already implies that treating SO as a helpdesk is OK... It's not. Karl's answer covers a lot already.

Comment: Allow me to assure you that I do not use SO as a helpdesk nor promote its usage in such a manner.  Identifying posted questions as encroaching on that category is not always black&white.  Stack Overflow as a company does not seem to want to defend itself from "giv me tha codez" questions.  There are certainly some "what does this do" (completely unresearched) questions which have become the basis for great answers.  The whole helpdesk topic is too grey to argue over.

Comment: Karl's answer is splitting hairs regarding "answering a question" vs "solving the problem" vs "implementing the advice" and it feels like arguing for arguing's sake to me.  When I answer something, I try to answer it comprehensively, educationally, with the intent to help the asker and thousands of future readers.  I don't make any distinction been "providing a solution" and "solving the asked question" and "implementing my advice".  If the question is so poorly asked that a correct answer cannot be implement by the asker, then there is surely something fundamentally bad about the question.

Comment: I'm not even going to answer this rambling. You complained your observations weren't taken as truths. I provided an explanation. I'm not interested in a convoluted discussion about specifics in your question or an answer. _Why don't you just take my explanation as truth?_

Comment: "Karl's answer is splitting hairs regarding "answering a question" vs "solving the problem" vs "implementing the advice"" - I think these ideas are quite clearly distinct, and in fact barely even related.

Comment: They are also secondary to the feature details (if relevant at all). The feature is not about what is an answer; it is about not rewarding posts on a page labelled as a signpost.

Answer (score 14):

> For askers who treat SO as a help desk, a dupe closure is a point of frustration because they want to receive answers specifically tailored to their question.

> For answerers who treat SO as a help desk (and say that they aren't here for the rep gains [...pfft]), a dupe closure is a point of frustration because tailored answers cannot be posted while the page is closed.

SO *is not* a help desk, and askers and answerers who treat it like one are misusing the site software and interfering with the site mission. It is not the goal of SO to provide tailored answers. **It is the goal of SO to provide *high-quality* answers**. A high-quality answer requires a high-quality question - which entails asking in a way that makes the question applicable to others. Tailoring the answer is generally *reducing* quality - except insofar as giving *one arbitrary* object example of a common problem is illustrative of the general pattern - because it entails *not* explaining things directly to the reader, but addressing the OP - from the ordinary reader's perspective, an unrelated third party.

Therefore, when setting site policy, there is absolutely no reason to consider the goals, aims or frustrations that are specific to these groups.

> For duplicate close voters who want to give tailored advice about how to implement the dupe target's advice, they can only shoehorn poorly-formatted text into comments under the question.

Speaking as someone who commonly gives "tailored" advice of this sort: I **don't want** to do this. I do it to preempt objections and try to mitigate how the site is perceived externally. And really, it is never about "how to implement" the advice - it is about **why** the OP's question is really an instance of the canonical.

The point of the site is not, will not be, and never was to get other peoples' code to work. It is to **answer questions**. As such, it's not part of the job to guide others with "implementing the advice". The job is to *communicate* the advice as clearly as possible.

> For careful/discerning answerers who are wary of answering a question which has a high probability of being a duplicate, they must burn minutes hunting for duplicates (while other users post carefree answers) despite being knowledgeable enough to answer immediately.

If a question has a high probability of being a duplicate, then it also has a high probability of having an acceptable answer. In fact, in many cases there are *way too many* answers, almost all of which are mediocre. The skill to discern such questions doesn't necessarily translate into skill at writing stellar answers.

But when it does, the people who write stellar answers **should feel more at home writing them for the best possible version of the question**, which ideally is also the one that gets all the search engine traffic and thus puts their stellar work in front of more eyeballs.

> Answerers are not meant to also vote to close duplicates because it can be seen as a technique to block competing answers from being posted.

It's the other way around. **Close voters are not meant to attempt answers**, because the purpose of close votes *is to signal that answers should not be attempted*.

> Despite SO's documented goal of getting answers on a specific topic in one place, duplicate close voting does not signal answerers to transfer their unique insights to the dupe target(s).

**How often do they actually have unique insights?**

For example, if I look at the [most "frequent" Python questions that aren't also about common specific technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+-pandas+-selenium-webdriver+-tkinter) - the ones most commonly used as duplicate targets - the top 30 questions, by my accounting, have an average of over 25 answers - and *all* of them have *at least* four.

> While some questions can be legitimately closed as a duplicate AND have some other aspect that makes the page unsuitable as a signpost, the system does not permit that dual distinction.

Sure it does. **That's what deletion is for.** An OP that doesn't ask a suitable new question, and also doesn't properly describe a suitable old question, is therefore not asking a suitable question at all. **It therefore has no place** on a question and answer site.

> instead withhold rep on signposts

Unsurprisingly, I like the sound of that. The rest of your points about the existing system are fine, and they naturally lead to that conclusion.

Comment: I fully disagree that "It is not the goal of SO to provide tailored answers.". Askers are expected to offer a MCVE and fully expect to receive answers which resolve the asked question. Answers from 2008 are absolutely horrible when they say: "RTM, call array_walk_recursive()`" These low-value, no-implementation hints are more akin to a comment versus actually being helpful and generous resolutions.  Every asker would prefer an answer WITH an implemented solution versus general guidance with no implementation. It is elitist to believe worthy readers can figure out implementations on their own.

Comment: If a question is clearly and accurately asked, resolving the question should also "get other peoples' code to work". Obviously.  Implementing the solution within the scope of the asked question while clearly communicating the resolving advice  is absolutely how one crafts an appropriate / generous / excellent answer. ... How often do people have unique insights? Since SO has MILLIONS of pages with answers, sharing something unique can be quite hard. If you are not aware that a new question is a duplicate, you might remain blissfully unaware that you actually only spew redundant insights.

Comment: Deletion is for content that cannot be rescued from "unfit-ness" or has otherwise been abandoned in an unfit state.  A question's identification as a signpost is a completely different evaluation from other close reasons. If a signpost is a sufficiently unique version of the scenario and does not suffer any close-worthy problems, it should stay alive as a signpost. If the page is unfit and cannot be rescued, delete it.  The decision to delete should be based on the question's quality in accordance with the site's on-topic guidelines.

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, then editing it cannot rescue it from the reason it was closed - since making it "not a duplicate" would require fundamentally changing what is being asked. Of course, sometimes the title can be fixed to make it a better signpost. But [per my previous stance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426214), if there is no such potential to redeem the question by editing, it should *only* be kept long-term if there is a *novel, otherwise-useful* answer that *doesn't get (re)moved*.

Comment: _I fully disagree that "It is not the goal of SO to provide tailored answers."_ You can __disagree__, @mickmackusa, but that doesn't make it true. A large part of your suggestions is based on your (incorrect) interpretation of how SO (should) work(s)... Which invalidates all of that.

Comment: @Karl "If the question is a duplicate, then editing it cannot rescue it from the reason it was closed" pertains to the current system. If my feature was implemented, "duplicateness" would no longer be a page closure reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus there is no true/false when it comes to what a "good" generous helpful question is. It is an opinion to say what is good, this is why is it okay for me to disagree.  Since my interpretation of what I think is best for this platform/system/community is subjective and personally formulated by my lived experience, it is an opinion and is not definable as correct/incorrect.  You are free to have your opinion and I am free to have mine.  Maybe you are fine with the status quo; I'm seeking initiative to try to improve user behavior.

Comment: @mickmackusa The ___goal___ and ___intended purpose___ of SO is not an opinion. It's defined by the company. There's nothing subjective about that. So yes, you ___are___ objectively incorrect there. You may find a question to be be helpful, but that does in _no_ way mean it's automatically part of the purpose/goal of SO.

Comment: The goals of SO are vague / poorly defined / open to interpretation.  For instance, _some_ duplicate questions are welcome ...well, how many is _some_? The company does not say.

Comment: Eh, no. Duplicates are duplicates... Duplicates should be closed as such. Please, province a official source that states some duplicates _shouldn't_ be closed.

Comment: That is the spark of this feature. It is challenging the convention in an attempt to change behavior.  We need more awareness that [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.) This feature urges users to post unique insights on open dupe targets.

Comment: @mickmackusa unfortunately meta does not fulfil that goal. Only a very small subset of people actually look here and those people are pretty convinced their idea of the truth is the truth. If you want to inspire change, you'll need to build up a popular Youtube channel. Then you have a voice in this day and age. Here? You're just shouting into an echo chamber mate :)

Answer (score 1):

> All upvotes and downvotes on the page will be tracked/presented normally, however, all reputation changes (including rep cost for downvoting) will be held in escrow (potentially indefinitely) while the page is marked as a "potential signpost".

I find that feature good neither from the answerer point of view, nor from the view of preventing duplicate answers:

1. [Answerer] Every good content is rewarded. Even answers on closed question give the reputation. The only not rewarded content is deleted content (because that content is not shown). Why an answer on a duplicate (I use current terminology) should be an exception? It is simply unfair to the person who creates that answer.
2. [Answerer] There is a difference between copy (stealing) answer from one question to the duplicate one and actually tailoring the solution with some modifications. The former answer should not exist at all, but the latter is actually a pearl. Why the latter answer is not awarded?
3. [Preventing duplicate answers] Once the duplicate mark will be removed, every answer to the duplicate question will give the reputation to the owner. Because of such possibility to gain reputation from the duplicate answers, such answers WILL be posted by "rep-motivated contributors". And it will be difficult to detect stolen answers, because you need to check many questions with "duplicate" relationship.

I agree that *some* duplicate questions will benefit from the tailoring answer(s). But bunch of duplicate answers (see point 3) far worse than that benefit.

Comment: 1. If a duplicate question is otherwise fit for Stack Overflow, why block contributors from answering it? Volunteers hate to be silenced, it's frustrating.  Instead, they can answer, but if they actually want to be rewarded, they need to post a unique answer on the dupe target. This is more fair than telling the user that they cannot post an answer. 2. Plagiarism should always be flagged and downvoted. Tailoring an answer seems fine to me. There is no system reward for answering a dupe because we want to incentivize getting all unique solutions for a topic in one place.

Comment: 3. Pages that have the signpost label removed will be in the change history. If someone is gaming the system, there will be proof. It can be addressed

Comment: Right now, there is ABSOLUTELY NO REASON/REWARD to search for duplicates or consolidate content.

Comment: "1. If a duplicate question is otherwise fit for Stack Overflow, why block contributors from answering it?" - Because we (SO) want all solutions to a single problem to be consolidated in the **single place**. "... if they actually want to be rewarded, they need to post a unique answer on the dupe target. This is more fair than telling the user that they cannot post an answer." - We want only **unique answers**, and it is perfectly allowed to post it in the duplicate (linked) target. In that aspect the current system works perfectly.

Comment: "2. Plagiarism should always be flagged and downvoted." - As stated in the point 3, it is difficult to detect plagiarism, if an answer on one question is copied from another question. That another question could be a duplicate target, or even another question with the same duplicate target. Currently it is sufficient to check answers only to the same question.

Comment: "3. Pages that have the signpost label removed will be in the change history. If someone is gaming the system, there will be proof. It can be addressed." - The point 3 is not about "gaming the system". If there is a **probability** that answering will get the reputation to a person, the rep-motivated contributors will post such answers. They will post answers even if such probability doesn't depend from them but from some other factors.

Comment: 1: No, the current system behaviour does not work correctly-- answers posted before the dupe closure are rewarded and unique insights are usually NOT transferred to the dupe target because there is nothing to provoke such activity. My feature does not reward answering a question before or after it is labelled a signpost. If an answer is posted, then upvoted or accepted, then labelled a signpost, then the answer is likely to notice the loss of rep and learn how/where/when to post answers. The feature is designed to steer unique insights to a **single place**.

Comment: 2: If you find content that is in anyway unhelpful or is plagiatism, then downvote it and potentially vote to delete the answer. Leave a comment explaining your issue with the post if you want to educate the answerer. If you downvote an answer on a signpost page  there will be no cost to the downvoter. If the page's signpost label is lifted, then your dv will cost `-1`.

Comment: 3: answerers are 100% free to waste their time posting loads of answers which will not earn them any points.  I am confident that even slow-learners will eventually learn what the system wants them to do.

Comment: @mickmackusa: It seems you treat useless answers which don't give reputation as answerer-only problem. But they are problem for **curators** too. We need to check their correctness (and express it via upvote/downvote), we need to edit them for fix grammar and representation issues. And, more vitally, we need to detect non-unique answers and delete them. "2: If you find content that is in anyway unhelpful or is plagiatism, then downvote it and potentially vote to delete the answer." - Again, the problem is not to *react* on plagiaism, the problem is to **detect** plagiaism.

Comment: If an answer to a signpost is not unique to SO, then users can downvote the answer if they wish (with no personal cost). This will make it easier for bad signpost answers to receive del-votes.  As content becomes better consolidated and related, it will only get easier to identify plagiarism.  I am sure AI enhancements will emerge to assist witj identifying duplicate/redundant advice on the site and plagiarism sourced from anywhere.

Comment: @mickmackusa - After you have answered a handful of questions, 2 reputation point, to downvote low quality answers is insignificant

Comment: @Sec ...okay, I agree, what is your point?